# body on load function not getting called if the script tag is end of the body

Tags: javascript, html

the code is somewhat like

```
<body onload="testFunc();">
    <div></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/test.js"></script>
</body>
```

and the testFunc is inside test.js
and sometimes its not getting called

Comment: Try moving the script outside the body

Comment: Yes will put up the script in head tag

Comment: Just wanted to know how the script tags and body onload happens

Answer (score 0):

The onload attribute fires when an object has been loaded.

onload is most often used within the  element to execute a script once a web page has completely loaded all content (including images, script files, CSS files, etc.).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("body loaded");
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">
<h1>body loaded!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```